# Meteor observeChanges vs manual update

Tags: meteor

I have a simple todo schema: (just a sample to draw my question)

```
{
  title: {
    type: string
  },
  value: {
    type: string
  },
  author: {
    type: object
  },
  "author._id": {
    type: string
  },
  "author.firstName": {
    type: string
  },
  "author.lastName": {
    type: string
  },
}
```

The author entries are from meteor.user. If the meteor user changes the firstName or lastName i have to update the todo. I have two possibilities:

1. observerChanges (server side) to users collection and update all todos from this user with the new firstname/lastname
2. if i call the user update method i can call a method to update all todos

when it's better to use cursor.observeChanges and when it's better to call a update method manual? And why?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't denormalize your data like this. In MongoDB you should just store the userId and look it up when necessary.

Comment: there are many different opinions about that:
check "2. Denormalization"
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but that post is nearly 2 years old now and there are newer solutions. Check out this package: [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) edit: I use it and would recommend it

Comment: ok, thanks. i will checkout this package.

Comment: publish-composite is nice but it comes with limitation: I started with it and ended up writing my own reactive joins because other packages like publish-counts or search don't work well with it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment says, you should not store the author name / email in the document if it is mutable:

Store the ID of the user only in the document, the UserID is immutable.

When building your ToDo template, look up the User information by ID: you would need to publish a Publication for user by Id, and subscribe to it on the client with the userId as parameter.

```
Meteor.publish('userById', function(userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: userId}, {limit:1});
});
```

in your route / template.onCreated depending on your Router, assuming the document is called doc

```
this.subscribe('userById', this.doc.author._id);
```

in the template helper

```
Template.todoTemplate.helpers({
   'Author': function() {
        return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.doc.author._id});
    }
});
```

and call the Author info in the template

```
<Template name="todoTemplate">
   First Name: {{Author.first_name}}
   Last Name: {{Author.last_name}}
</Template>
```

Comment: sorry but this is not a answer to my question. the question is, when it's better to use observerChanges and when to update an e.g. related collection by a method call. how to denormalize data in mongo is an other question.

Comment: well, when is it better? when the performance is better, or when complexity is lower. Sometimes it's better to denormalize, in this case it is not. observeChange will be running in the background continuously; update will be a one time thing when you do update. It all depends on how often you expect things to change, but I guess it will be little... So I would go with update in this case if that's my only 2 choices, but if I have the freedom to design I would not denormalize here.

Comment: an other sample:
`code`
    Passwords.find({}).observeChanges({
        removed: function (id) {
            PasswordsVaults.remove({_passwordId: id});
            PasswordRequests.remove({"password._id": id});
        },
`code`

this should not be done with observerChanges?

Comment: Your question is a problem of frequency: if changes happen fairly often, observing changes is a good way, but comes at the expense of having a hook setup al the time. a method call might to be slower as it is a call to the server, but when it's a sporadic event, it ends up requiring less resources.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't rely on the second method, because sometimes you (or your teammate) might forget to update it. Moreover, if you're denormalizing user data in other collections, **users knowing Meteor might just call your Meteor.method or manipulate db from the browser console**...

You can use this package:
`meteor add matb33:collection-hooks`

It adds some hooks to your mongo insert/update/remove call

For example:

```
Meteor.users.after.update(function (userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier, options) {
  if (this.previous.firstName === doc.firstName && this.previous.lastName === doc.lastName) {
    return;
  }
  Todos.update({'author._id': doc._id}, {
    $set: {
      'author.firstName': doc.firstName,
      'author.lastName': doc.lastName,
    }
  })
}, {fetchPrevious: true})
```

(To update the Todos collection efficiently, make sure to add index to author field)

This is just a handier way than writing your own `observeChanges`, and better than manually updating Todos collection every time you update the users collection, because you might forgot to call it in some case, or some hacker user just calls `Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), {...})` perhaps...

But still, I think you should always add some auto-correct mechanism to avoid wrong data being displayed, because no matter which method you choose, some error will occur (maybe the server watching the db just crashes right after users update). You can check on the client side when displaying content, if author.firstName doesn't match `Meteor.users.findOne(author._id)` (but you have to publish the user though...), than call a method to tell the server to update it.